# Get values separated by pipe ("|") in C#

Tags: c#, csv

A column in my csv file has data structured as `MajorGroup|Groups>Subgroup>item|SecondGroup`.

This code checks for the value before the first ">"

`var temp = columns[5].Split('|', '>');`

That is, the values "MajorGroup", and assigns it to a variable category:

`Category = temp[0].`

This returns "MajorGroup".

How do I get check for both "MajorGroup" and "SecondGroup" in the column. That is, the two values separated by the "|", and assign them both to `category`.

How do I get the first and last groups separated by the "|" and assign them both to `Category`.

For example, using products, the current code places a product only in the category "MajorGroups". I want to place the product in both the "MajorGroups" and "SecondGroup" categories. So that if I browse under either category I should see the product. Currently I would only see the products under the first category.

Comment: Use CSV Parsing library which allows specifying custom separators. You'll find many of them in google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
var temp = columns[5].Split('|').Where(inp => inp.IndexOf('>') < 0).ToArray();
```

this will strip out the subcategories. with give you an array with just the Major and Secondary

temp[0] will be MajorGroup
temp[1] will be SecondGroup

Comment: ok, but how do I set the category as both groups? `Category = temp[0].`. How do I set this to be both groups so that when I browse for the product, it can be found in both of the categories?

Comment: What is the type of Category? Just a string? To hold both values it would need to be an array, or a list.

Comment: Yes a string. I am trying to add it here but isn't working. I get array errors. ` items.Add(new Item()
        {
            Id = int.Parse(columns[0]),
            Name = columns[1],
            Description = columns[2], 
            Category = temp[0]
        });`

Comment: ` string[] Category = new string[] {temp[0],temp[1]}` not working. Errors

Comment: Can you change the type of Category in the items class to string[]? Then you can just have Category = temp

Comment: It is set to string ` public string Category { get; set; }` in my product class

Comment: are you able to change it to; public string[] Category { get; set; }

Comment: I also tried `Category = new string[] {temp[0],temp[1]}` but I get the error "cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'"

Comment: The type you are assigning, has to match that of the variable.

Comment: ok, but one question about this. Not all my products will have a category with two values. Most would have only one category. Would changing this to an array break things? Or does your code cater for this?

Comment: If there is only one category, `Category` will still be an array, but will only have one value in it. You would just have to make sure when using `Category` that you refer to it as an array, so it will be `Category[0]` and `Category[1]`. Only having one main category means it will just have `Category[0]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46713/discussion-between-tester-and-andy)